# get axes ticks in matplotlib before drawing the figure

Tags: matplotlib

How to get tick labels for a matplotlib axis without invoking `plt.show` first? I am trying to set up a bunch of subplots, manipulate their window limits and tick labels, and then bring it all on the screen together. However, `get_xticklabels()` method returns empty strings unless `plt.show` is called:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.plot(1, 1)    

print("before plt.show(): {}".format(ax.get_xticklabels()[0].get_text()))
plt.show()
print("after plt.show(): {}".format(ax.get_xticklabels()[0].get_text()))
```

Output:

```
In [33]: %run plt_premature_ticks.py
before plt.show():
after plt.show(): 0.94
```

Is it not an expected behavior to try getting the labels *before* the figure is actually shown?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `fig.canvas.draw()` before `ax.get_xticklabels()`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.plot(1, 1)    
fig.canvas.draw()
print("before plt.show(): {}".format(ax.get_xticklabels()[0].get_text()))
plt.show()
print("after plt.show(): {}".format(ax.get_xticklabels()[0].get_text()))
```

Answer (score 1):

While [HYRY](https://stackoverflow.com/users/772649/hyry) gave a correct answer to the original question, I've come across a few cases where one would need to call the `draw` method of an *axis* instance to get the tick labels visible. In that case, the following should be called:

```
renderer = fig.canvas.get_renderer()
ax.draw(renderer)
```